# Multiple checkbuttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying taking to make a GUI application using Python and tkinter. In this example I want the user to select multiple different fruits, and this should then set that fruit's value in a dictionary to True.

However, I'm using a for loop to generate the checkbuttons, and whenever I run, the program just sets the last fruit (Mango) to True, regardless of which button was checked. The code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

def true_in_dict(fruit):
    dict_fruits[fruit] = True
    print(dict_fruits)

window = tk.Tk()

lbl_fruits = tk.Label(master=window, text="Select fruits:")
lbl_fruits.grid(row=0, sticky="w")
frm_fruits = tk.Frame(master=window)
frm_fruits.grid(row=1, column=0)

dict_fruits = {"Apple": False,
               "Orange": False,
               "Pear": False,
               "Banana": False,
               "Mango": False}

for i, k in enumerate(dict_fruits):
    chkVal = tk.BooleanVar()
    chkVal.set(False)
    chk_fruit = tk.Checkbutton(master=frm_fruits, text=k, variable=chkVal, command=lambda: true_in_dict(k))
    chk_fruit.grid(row=i, column=0,sticky="w")

window.mainloop()
```

Do I need to make a dictionary of checkbuttons to get round this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: When the code is run, the loop completely gets executed and hence `k` becomes `Mango` and hence when you press the button always `Mango` is set to `True`. It doesnt wait for you to select something.

Comment: That's what I thought, but wasn't sure how to get round this. Will I have to just write out each button explicitly, rather than using a for loop?

Comment: Actually never mind, solved using `lamba k=k: true_in_dict(k)`

Comment: Thats why the Q was marked as duplicate ;)